# Event listener works only once. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have an event listener:

```
document.onclick = getMousePosition;
function getMousePosition(e) {
    var _x;
    var _y;
    if (!isIE) {
        _x = e.pageX;
        _y = e.pageY;
    }
    if (isIE) {
        _x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
        _y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    }

    posX = _x;
    posY = _y;

    if(posX > 640 & posX < 741 & posY > 70 & posY < 77) {
        var seek = posX - 640;
        story.currentTime = story.duration * seek /100;
        timeline.style.width = seek + "px";
        window.scrollBy(0, 7100 * seek / 100);
}
```

Now when i click once this function works good, but there is no reaction on next clicks. Should I setup it maybe kind of recursively? I use Google Chrome.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?  Errors can kill an event listener.

Comment: *"but there is no reaction on next clicks"* Maybe the `if` condition is not fulfilled? [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820), set some breakpoints, inspect variables, etc.

Comment: Felix Kling thanks! You r right, the if statement doesn't work second time. Thanks for link!

Comment: Felix very well knew the `if` condition is not passed ; ). `&` is a bitwise [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators), use `&&` for testing logically.